# Django - Sending error report email in try-except code

Tags: python, django, error-handling

Is it possible to hook into Django's built in error reporting emails from a `try`-`except` code block? In other words, email the default error report and stack trace to the `ADMINS`/`MANAGERS` while still having situation specific error handling.

**Specific example:**

In a project performing complex calculations and generating large reports, the view displaying the report page does all the calculations and generates a long html page with lots of pretty tables and graphs and also generates downloadable PDFs from sections of that same HTML.

Recently we had errors in the PDF generation from issues with storage on S3. Now this is obviously an error we need to track down and attend, but most users are happy if they can just see the report on screen. If the PDFs download links just weren't displayed the issue could go entirely unnoticed for hours or even days - but the dev team should be notified.

---

Ideally, but not necessarily, I would love a solution that is logger agnostic, where it will use whatever error logger is used and trigger the default 500 error handler, and return back to the `finally` block or after the `except` block.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to use Python's logging framework to raise an appropriate message at the appropriate level.  In your `settings.py` there is a `LOGGING` variable that defines how things are logged.  By default I believe Django has any `ERROR` in `django.request` will be handled by `mail_admins`.

So in your code, all you need to do is

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # this will create a logger with the module being the logger name

try:
    #do stuff you watch to catch
except:
    # we're going to catch and just log it
    logger.error('Some error title', exc_info=True) # exc_info=True will include the stacktrace
finally:
   # what you want to do in your finally block.
```

Note, this will swallow the exception and won't bubble it up.  Your response will return as a 200.  If you want to bubble up the exception, just call `raise` in your `except` block.  However, if all you care about is logging the error, but the view is still functional, then just log and swallow it.

In your `LOGGING` variable, you can add additional entries to loggers for the different logger names.  You can have an app log at a different logging status, say `INFO` if you want to debug a certain code path.  As long as you create a logger with the module name, you have a lot of flexibility of segmenting your logging to different handlers such as `mail_admins.`

Lastly, I'd recommend to look into [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry), as it's a really great error logging tool.